# Foreign key references invalid column error in MS SQL

Tags: sql

This is all in MS SQL.

I've seen this issue pop up a lot, and I searched around but I still can't figure out my issue. I'm getting the error telling me my foreign key references in invalid column in an uncreated table. However, I created the table as it shows up on my database table list, so it shows it is created.

I tried to move that said table above the table that references it, yet I'm still receiving the error. Would anyone know how to fix this?

My code:

```
CREATE SCHEMA usr_in;
go

CREATE TABLE gender_interst (
    id int IDENTITY (1,1),
    gend_id int
    CONSTRAINT gender_interstpk PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE TABLE gender (
id int IDENTITY (1,1),
gend VARCHAR (20)
CONSTRAINT genderpk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

SELECT * FROM gender_interst LEFT JOIN gender on gender_interst.id = gender.id;

SELECT * from gender_interst;

CREATE TABLE user_info (
    id int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1,1),
    usr_name VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
    f_name VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
    l_name VARCHAR (30),
    b_day DATE,
    email VARCHAR  (120) NOT NULL,
    genderpkid VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT gender_fk FOREIGN KEY (genderpkid) REFERENCES gender (genderpk),
);


INSERT
  INTO user_info 
     ( usr_name, f_name, l_name, b_day, genderpkid, email)
VALUES 
     ('JMAN', 'JOHN', 'DOE', '1990-01-01','M','EX@EMAIL'),
     ('JAM','JANE', 'DOE', '1995-05-02','F','EX@EMAIL'),
     ('NMAN','NICK', 'WEBB', '1999-06-22','M','EX@EMAIL'),
     ('LOBA','LOLA', 'LILLY', '1994-01-08','F','EX@EMAIL'),
     ('NOTSPMAN','PETER', 'PARKER','1985-11-25','M','EX@EMAIL');

SELECT * FROM user_info;
```

Comment: I got this error -- stupid mistake: I had forgot to include the 'USE [MyDatabase]' statement first, since my default database was master.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your foreign key needs to reference the name of a table column (which is either `id` or `gend`) and not the name of the primary key (`genderpk`).

Therefore the foreign key script (`CONSTRAINT gender_fk FOREIGN KEY (genderpkid) REFERENCES gender (genderpk)`) should look something like `CONSTRAINT gender_fk FOREIGN KEY (genderpkid) REFERENCES gender (id)`

However to create the relationship the two columns need to have the same data type. `user_info .genderpkid` is `VARCHAR (10)` and `user_info.id` is `int`.

The other problem you might encounter is that the insert scripts insert the data into `genderpkid` column as `M` or `F`. Therefore int is not going to work

If you were to use use the values M or F for gender, then you can create a script like:

```
CREATE TABLE gender (
    id VARCHAR (1),
    gender VARCHAR (20)
    CONSTRAINT gender_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE user_info (
    id int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1,1),
    usr_name VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
    f_name VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
    l_name VARCHAR (30),
    b_day DATE,
    email VARCHAR  (120) NOT NULL,
    genderId VARCHAR (1) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT gender_fk FOREIGN KEY (genderId) REFERENCES gender (id),
);

INSERT INTO gender (id, gender)
VALUES 
('F', 'Female'),
('M', 'Male')

INSERT
  INTO user_info 
     ( usr_name, f_name, l_name, b_day, genderId, email)
VALUES 
     ('JMAN', 'JOHN', 'DOE', '1990-01-01','M','EX@EMAIL'),
     ('JAM','JANE', 'DOE', '1995-05-02','F','EX@EMAIL'),
     ('NMAN','NICK', 'WEBB', '1999-06-22','M','EX@EMAIL'),
     ('LOBA','LOLA', 'LILLY', '1994-01-08','F','EX@EMAIL'),
     ('NOTSPMAN','PETER', 'PARKER','1985-11-25','M','EX@EMAIL');

SELECT * FROM user_info;
```

A better approach could be, to pass the whole phraze (male / female) to the table `user_info`. The table `gender` can be used to enforce `referential integrity`. All your information is then contained in `SELECT * FROM user_info`

**For example:**

```
  CREATE TABLE gender (
        [name] VARCHAR (20)
        CONSTRAINT gender_pk PRIMARY KEY ([name])
    );
    
    CREATE TABLE user_info (
        id int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1,1),
        usr_name VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
        f_name VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
        l_name VARCHAR (30),
        b_day DATE,
        email VARCHAR  (120) NOT NULL,
        gender VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
        genderIntrest VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT gender_fk FOREIGN KEY (gender) REFERENCES gender ([name]),
        CONSTRAINT genderIntrest_fk FOREIGN KEY (genderIntrest) REFERENCES gender ([name]),
    );
    
    INSERT INTO gender ([name])
    VALUES 
    ('Female'),
    ('Male')
    
    INSERT
      INTO user_info 
         ( usr_name, f_name, l_name, b_day, gender, genderIntrest, email)
    VALUES 
         ('JMAN', 'JOHN', 'DOE', '1990-01-01','Male','Female', 'EX@EMAIL'),
         ('JAM','JANE', 'DOE', '1995-05-02','Female','Female', 'EX@EMAIL'),
         ('NMAN','NICK', 'WEBB', '1999-06-22','Male','Female','EX@EMAIL'),
         ('LOBA','LOLA', 'LILLY', '1994-01-08','Female','Female','EX@EMAIL'),
         ('NOTSPMAN','PETER', 'PARKER','1985-11-25','Male','Female','EX@EMAIL');
    
    SELECT * FROM user_info;
```

You can remove the gender table and let the app that consumes it pass in the data. However for a learning exercises, it's probably better to leave it in

Comment: Thank you, this helps me understand what is going on a lot better,

The intention of this is a simple assignment project in SQL. I decided to work on a dating site since it seemed like a simple protect. I was going to create a main table which holds the user information, then another table that holds the gender information, along side points to another table that stores their gender orientation. 

This was all to help reduce redundancies in the overall DB.

However, we were told about the project not too long ago, and started to learn about SQL that same day. Would this version work?

Comment: If you're saying user_info has one gender and one orientation. Then you don't really need a relationship as it's one-to-one. However by having the relationship you can force the table 'user_info' to only accept certain values (e.g 'male' / 'female'). In which case you can remove ID from the table gender and just join on the full description. (If it was me, I would stick to one table)

Comment: Are you saying just having a single table, user_info, should be enough to input the gender, and having another table for gender selection/orientation isn't necessary?

Comment: I've updated the answer. Generally I would say a single table is sufficient. As a learning exercise I would say have 2 tables.